# Set the snapshot frequency for Memgraph Platform?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I change the snapshot frequency for Memgraph Platform? I'm running the latest Docker version of the Platform (MG 2.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll need to modify the Memgraph configuration file. Since you are running a Docker it will involve some copy/edit/copy back operations:

1. Start Memgraph Platform with including the `-v mg_etc:/etc/memgraph` flag:

   docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -e MEMGRAPH="--log-level=TRACE" 
   -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph 
   -v mg_log:/var/log/memgraph 
   -v mg_etc:/etc/memgraph 
   memgraph/memgraph-platform
2. Find the `CONTAINER ID` of the Memgraph Docker:

   docker ps
3. Copy the configuration file from the container to your local machine:

   docker cp :/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf memgraph.conf
4. Open the configuration file with a text editor, and modify the `--snapshot-interval-sec` option to set the desired snapshot frequency in seconds. Save the changes to the configuration file.
5. Copy the modified configuration file back to the container:

   docker cp memgraph.conf :/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf

Now restart the docker and your new configuration will be loaded.